# JTextField ActionListener not responding to event

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am writing a java application which displays the contents of a SQLite database.

I am trying to set up an ActionListener, so that the user can click on the field and the program will access the next table in the database.

The problem is the listener is not responding to the click.

Blow is the method I am using to create the JTextField and set up the listener:

```
public void text(JTextField jtf, String a, int x, int y, int wid, int hei){

        Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,12);
        gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        jtf=new JTextField(a);
            gbc.gridx=x;
            gbc.gridy=y;
            gbc.gridwidth = wid;
            gbc.gridheight=hei;
            gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;           
            add(jtf,gbc);
            jtf.setEditable(false);
            jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            jtf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            jtf.setFont(font); 
            jtf.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {               @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Pressed");
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: `The problem is the listener is not responding to the click`. A correctly added ActionListener won't fire when you click on the JTextField.  It will fire when the focus is in the JTextField, then hit ENTER.  Perhaps you want to add the listener to a JButton instead?

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the example will reveal the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ActionListener executes when the user has focus on the control and presses ENTER.

You should use a mouseListener in order to listen to events involving the mouse.

```
jtf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Released");
   }

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Pressed");
   }
}
```

You can also use a keyListener if you want to respond to the user changing the text.

Comment: addMouseListener does not seem to work for JTextField, but you gave me the right idea and I have now used a button with a white background which solves the problem